# I want to show numbers in "From - To" Format

Tags: c#, sorting

I have multiple random numbers in table column ID like

```
8v12027
8v12025
8v12024
8v12029.       
8v12023
8v12030
8v12020
```

O/p -  8v12020, From 8v12023 To 8v12025, 8v12027,     From 8v12029 To 8v12030,

Comment: In c# or SQL server

Comment: I might not be fully awake yet, but I can't figure out what your criteria is for which numbers get paired together. Also, does the `.` mean anything?

Comment: No meaning for .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'are waiting for an sql solution so :
You have to use `Lead` or `Lag` `KeyWord` and concat it.

```
SELECT CONCAT('From ',Id,'To :', LEAD(p.Id) OVER (ORDER BY p.Id),'s') FROM YourTable p
```

There is a really good explanation about thoses keyword in the sqlauthority web site.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

But If you were waiting for a pure C# solution, you can retreive the data set in an Array, after order it by Id and concat and with a for loop concat current value with previous (or next) one. 
Or with a Linq use Aggregate

```
yourArray.Aggregate((a,b)=> String.Concat("From ",a," To ",b,";")).Split(';')
```